# Assertion failed in pycurl when trying to get image from web

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I'm trying to get an image from a site with this code:

```
image="http://the.site.com/view/ashx/Handler.ashx?Command=Avatar&TC=TQB"
curlobj = pycurl.Curl()
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, '')
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30)
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 30)
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.FAILONERROR, True)
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
imgf = open("logo.jpg", "wb")
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.URL, image)
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, imgf)
curlobj.perform()
imgf.close()
curlobj.close()
```

But it gives:

```
python2`.6: src/pycurl.c:272: get_thread_state: Assertion `self->ob_type == p_Curl_Type' failed.`
```

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: At which line do you get this error? How did you install pycurl (and libcurl and python, if they didn't come built in with your system)? And what versions?

Comment: @abarnert: it doesn't raise exception and doesn't gives line!! there is just this error; but using debugger it occurs at the `.perform()` line; I installed pycurl from Ubuntu's repositories (version 7.19.0-3 on Lucid Lynx) and python (version 2.6.5) is pre-installed on Ubuntu. `libcurl` is 7.19.7

Answer (score 0):

When my code developed this error, it was able to be fixed by ensuring that curl/pycurl did not reuse existing connections.

If you enable c.setopt(c.VERBOSE , 1) before c.perform() it will provide more (debug) information in the output, and the first few lines should tell you if it is establishing a new connection at the beginning of c.perform().

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `setopt` `VERBOSE`. So I saw that there was in fact *no* redirect and the content was already loaded (I saw all the response headers together with proper `Content-Length`. Still the `assert` in `pycurl.c` hits. And I really have to keep my `curl` instance alive because it carries a cookie. Any ideas?

Comment: Found the issue: If I `Connection: keep-alive` and reuse the same `curl` instance, then of course this will make sense only when all the `perform()`s with this `curl` address the same `netloc` (hostname). Shame on me. But maybe it helps someone else :)